# TINYMCE add input filed after click add image

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, tinymce

I looking for some ideas for solve my problem.

I use TINYMCE for add text on my page. I would like that after adding a picture to the text, in my form appeared options tag with text, that will be appear on the top of photo.

Have you any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Please show us what you already tried.

Comment: Add input field? Or input file?

Comment: Please show existing code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you to do is to utilize existing image_caption option from it's image plugin.

[image]

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/

Which will wrap the embeded image with the follow:

```
<figure class="image">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" alt="" />
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Use css style set your caption on top of the image

```
figure.image {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

figure.image > figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v90vqt48/4/